# Vscode shows function docstrings twice when using jedi + pyright

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, python-jedi, pyright

I am using VSCodium (an open source version of vscode) with jedi and pyright installed. This leads to function docstrings getting displayed twice (see attached picture), as jedi and pyright both show them.

Is there a way to disable this single feature for jedi without disabling jedi completely?[image: screenshot]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It turns out that Pyright itself is a language server and therefore vscode shows both the output of pyright and jedi at the same time. Adding `"python.languageServer": "None",` in your config fixes this.

See also: https://github.com/microsoft/pyright/issues/390, https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-python/issues/7010 and https://github.com/microsoft/pyright/issues/201

Update: An alternative approach is to continue using jedi or any other language server and just set "pyright.disableLanguageServices" to true.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try to switch to Pylance Language Server? `pyright` has built-in it:

> Pyright has detected that the Pylance extension is installed. Pylance
> includes the functionality of Pyright, and running both of these
> extensions can lead to problems. Pyright will disable itself.
> Uninstall or disable Pyright to avoid this message.

Comment: Unfortunately Pylance does not fulfill my requirements as it is not open source. Otherwise with VSCode (not VSCodium) pylance works well.

Comment: @T-Dawg Yeah, agree with that.